# Arabic and German in ConTeXt

Tags: context, languages, arabic

I'm totally new to ConTeXt; how to use Arabic and German in one document?

```
\mainlanguage[de]

\definefont[ArabicFont][file:alq2.ttf*arabic at 18pt]

\setuppapersize [A5] 

\starttext
\setupalign[r2l]
\ArabicFont

بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ

\stoptext
```

How to modify, so that I can swith between Arabic and German? (I knew LaTeX, and have defined there some macros, but here everything might change...)

Comment: Possibly related question: [how to switch fonts via language switches](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59523/14066). Are you primarily interested in a *font* or a *hyphenation* switch?

Comment: I am not sure about the difference. The solution in the link is far too complicated for me, I just want an environment like \begin{arab} Arabtext in unicode \end{arab}, which I always used in LaTex, but I dont know how to make that.

Comment: Have you seen the information at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Arabic_and_Hebrew ? It should get you going.

Comment: Yes, but that does not work for me. Now I have made an environment, which begins arabic font by

    \def\Arab{\setupalign[r2l]\ArabicFont}

But how to switch back to normal (german) text? Best, I would have an option \startarabic ... \stoparabic, but how to make that?

Comment: Ok, done, I had to investigate the start/stop commands in ConTeXt, now it works.

Comment: @Mustafa: if you have found a solution, please write it down below as an answer, and accept it. That will help other people who have the same question.

Comment: You are right, of course, I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

```
\startenvironment arabic
\definefont[Sheh][name:Scheherazade*arabic at 12pt]

\definestartstop[Arab][commands=\setups{Arabic}]
\def\Arab{\dodoubleempty\doArab}
\def\Arab[#1]{
\startArab 
\setupalign[r2l]\Sheh #1
\stopArab
}
\stopenvironment
```

Where the Font is the famous Sheherazade. But there should be one enhancement: The grid=yes should be disabled in this environment, since the grid is not suitable for arabic letters. I dont know how to do that, to add simply \setuplayout[grid=no] to the environment does not work, seems to be overwritten by the \setuplayout[grid=yes] of the mainfile.

Comment: But this is no complete answer, as I see now! For


    \Arab[
يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلنَّاسُ ٱتَّقُوا۟ رَ‌بَّكُمُ ٱلَّذِى خَلَقَكُم مِّن نَّفْسٍ وَٰحِدَةٍ وَخَلَقَ مِنْهَا زَوْجَهَا وَبَثَّ مِنْهُمَا رِ‌جَالًا كَثِيرً‌ۭا وَنِسَآءً وَٱتَّقُوا۟ ٱللَّـهَ ٱلَّذِى تَسَآءَلُونَ بِهِۦ وَٱلْأَرْ‌حَامَ إِنَّ ٱللَّـهَ كَانَ عَلَيْكُمْ رَ‌قِيبًا
    ]

has far too many space between the arabic lines. Why?

Comment: I solved this, see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77847/line-spacing-in-arabic-in-context-how-to-deactivate-gridsetting-in-an-environm