# Line spacing in Arabic in ConTeXt - how to deactivate gridsetting in an environment

Tags: context, line-spacing, arabic, grid-typesetting

I realize Arabic in ConTeXt with the following environment (to be able to switch between German and Arabic).

```
\startenvironment arab-besser-sty
\definefont[Sheh][name:Scheherazade*arabic at 15pt] % or file:amiri-regular.ttf*... file:alq.ttf
\definestartstop[Arab][commands=\setups{Arabic}]
\def\Arab{\doArab}
\def\Arab[#1]{
\startArab 
\setupalign[r2l]\Sheh #1
\stopArab
}

\stopenvironment
```

Everything works fine, but with my Standard-Setup:

```
\environment arab-besser-sty

\setuplayout[location=middle,
topspace=1cm,
width=middle,
cutspace=2.7cm,
rightmargindistance=0.4cm,
leftmargindistance=0.2cm,
backspace=1.5cm,
height=fit,
rightmargin=2.5cm,
leftmargin=1cm,
bottomspace=1.5cm,
footer=1.2cm,
grid=yes]
```

The line-space between arabic lines is far too much, why, and how to fix this without disturbing the above standard-layout?

Full Minimal Example:

```
    \environment arab-besser-sty

\setuplayout[location=middle,
  topspace=1cm,
  width=middle,
  cutspace=2.7cm,
  rightmargindistance=0.4cm,
  leftmargindistance=0.2cm,
  backspace=1.5cm,
  height=fit,
  rightmargin=2.5cm,
  leftmargin=1cm,
  bottomspace=1.5cm,
  footer=1.2cm,
  grid=yes]

\starttext

\Arab[

يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلنَّاسُ ٱتَّقُوا۟ رَ‌بَّكُمُ ٱلَّذِى خَلَقَكُم مِّن نَّفْسٍ وَٰحِدَةٍ وَخَلَقَ مِنْهَا زَوْجَهَا وَبَثَّ مِنْهُمَا رِ‌جَالًا كَثِيرً‌ۭا وَنِسَآءً وَٱتَّقُوا۟ ٱللَّـهَ ٱلَّذِى تَسَآءَلُونَ بِهِۦ وَٱلْأَرْ‌حَامَ إِنَّ ٱللَّـهَ كَانَ عَلَيْكُمْ رَ‌قِيبًا ﴿١﴾ وَءَاتُوا۟ ٱلْيَتَـٰمَىٰٓ أَمْوَٰلَهُمْ وَلَا تَتَبَدَّلُوا۟ ٱلْخَبِيثَ بِٱلطَّيِّبِ وَلَا تَأْكُلُوٓا۟ أَمْوَٰلَهُمْ إِلَىٰٓ أَمْوَٰلِكُمْ إِنَّهُۥ كَانَ حُوبًا كَبِيرً‌ۭا ﴿٢﴾ وَإِنْ خِفْتُمْ أَلَّا تُقْسِطُوا۟ فِى ٱلْيَتَـٰمَىٰ فَٱنكِحُوا۟ مَا طَابَ لَكُم
]

Too much line space above.

\stoptext
```

Comment: Add: How to disable grid=yes for a command like the above \Arab? I think that would solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution. I set the environment `Arab` into `\placeongrid[bottom]{...}`, that works quite well.