# ConTeXt: Cyrillic letters are not rendered

Tags: context, cyrillic

Okay, a really stupid question. How do I compile my Hello World document with Cyrillic letters? Compiling

```
\starttext
\startsection[title={Testing ConTeXt}]
  This is my {\em first} русский ConTeXt document.
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

gives

[image: note that the Russian word is absent]

Note that the Russian word just disappeared. The log doesn't contain any warnings or errors.

Searching yields a lot of info about making Cyrillic work in LaTeX, but I haven't found anything for ConTeXt. The [Encodings and Regimes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Encodings_and_Regimes) page on Context Garden just says

> in LuaTeX (MkIV) 
>   you can normally forget about font encodings

which is obviously not the case. Any thoughts on this?

ConTeXt version is 2013.84.svn30044-18.5 (`context --version` shows 2013.04.20 01:15); `luatex --version` shows `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2015102513 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (rev 4627)`.

Comment: Have you loaded a font containing Cyrillic glyphs?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm not sure I did. I've only installed a package named `texlive-cyrillic`, but didn't add any font loading commands anywhere.

Comment: Quite old context.

Comment: The default font, Latin modern does not include Cyrillic glyphs. Pick a font that does.

Comment: Does this help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59523/how-to-switch-fonts-when-the-language-switches-in-context

Comment: @HenriMenke yes, very useful link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a font that has Cyrillic glyphs. One such free font is [Dejavu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page). If you have it installed, then the following should work:

```
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]
\starttext
\startsection[title={Testing ConTeXt}]
  This is my {\em first} русский ConTeXt document.
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\enabletrackers[fonts.missing]
\starttext
\startsection[title={Testing ConTeXt}]
  This is my {\em first} русский ConTeXt document.
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

Comment: I don't know much about ConTeXt, so why would tracking fonts help? Would it solve the answer?

Comment: As JosephWright said, it can be  that the font used has no ghyphs in that area. In this case the tracker records on the log something like 

"fonts           > checking > char й (U+00439) in font 'LMRoman12-Regular' with id 1: missing" 

for each glyph missed.

Comment: Okay, and how does it answer the question then?

Comment: The problem can be a combination of 1) missing glyphs in the  font used to typeset the text. The default font depends on the format; 2) bug in the font used 3) bug in the  format; 4) bug in the engine.
For the examples as in this question, 
and under the assumption that the content of the log is known by the author, in 99% of cases the format is cont-en with the Latin Modern font and the luatex engine: this font doesn't have the glyphs of the chars (case 1) )  so the answer  is a) change the font (as shown by Aditya) or  or b) use a font fallaback (as suggested by  Henri Menke). (cont.)

Comment: ...by Henri Menke).
To cover the rest 1% it's necessary to know at least  if the format (which can be different from default cont-en)  recognises that there are missing glyphs, (and in cont-en the macro `\enabletrackers[fonts.missing]` does this)
otherwise it can be a bug in the font/format/engine.
Of course `\enabletrackers[fonts.missing]` is also valid in the other 99% of the cases.

Comment: @LuigiScarso this an extremely useful command, thanks a lot man.